# Change all hrefs so their native url shows on a website

Tags: jquery

I am trying to come up with jQuery that would make all the hrefs on a website show their native url.

For instance this url:

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">W3Schools</a>
```

would normally be visible as *W3Schools*

but I'd like to see the native url instead: *http://www.w3schools.com*

```
$(function(){
    $('a').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('href', 'this is where I need help');
    });
});
```

The jQuery above is definitely a good start. Although, as it is it would actually change all the href values to "this is where I need help".

Would any kind soul be able and willing to assist me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this by looping over the anchors and changing their text to the href value.

```js
$(function() {
  $('a').each(function() {
    $(this).text(this.href);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">W3Schools</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much that worked like a charm. There is a last thing I would like to do and that is to add trailing slash at the end of each url. Would it be possible to implement to your solution?

Comment: @TomášJanulík You could do `$(this).text(this.href + '/');`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.attr()` like such:

```
var links = $(this).attr('href');
```

```js
$(function(){
  $('a').each(function() {
    var links = $(this).attr('href');
    $(this).text(links);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com">W3Schools</a>
```

Comment: Wonderful! That's exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, @TomášJanulík